# A Question Regarding Negative Reputation

Tags: feature-request, answers, downvoting

Some answer to this question [Black screen after login with cursor](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297112/black-screen-after-login-with-cursor), I gave him down vote & suddenly i loose the 1 point, can any one guide me how it work ?

> Given Down Vote To Answer

[image]

> Loosing 1 Reputation

[image]

Comment: Also, go ahead and flag that answer as "not an answer" it's not an answer and should be deleted.

Comment: Also, I just deleted that answer. You should get your reputation back (since it truly was a bad answer) sooner or later.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi The duplicate flagged answer say : " It's there to help stop people gaming the system " > ( eg posting an answer and then downvoting everybody else to make their post the top of the pile), I haven’t posted any answer

Comment: That's one of the many reasons it's there. It's not just because you post an answer, downvoting effectively takes rep away from the other user, so as acknowledgement of this it also takes -1 from you (far less than what it takes from the other user). http://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation This is just to prevent people in general from robbing users of reputation (think rage downvoting) without it having an effect on that person. You should always downvote when needed, don't let a -1 here and there throw you off when a +10 is right around the corner :)

Comment: @MarcoCeppi ... Thanks for the detail ..